# Passing user input into GQL Queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, react-apollo

I am currently trying to figure out how to implement a search function by using the text data the user submits through a form as a variable argument in the query that returns an array of the results. The results from the AssetQueryInit query render just fine. (AssetQueryInit just renders the results of a hardcoded query)

I am a newbie and any help would be appreciated!

GraphQL Server

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Asset {
    _id: ID
    assetName: String
    headline: String
    language: String
    sentimentNegative: Float
    sentimentNeutral: Float
    sentimentPositive: Float
    firstCreated: String


  }
  type Query {
    asset(assetName: String!): Asset
    assetAll(assetName: String!): [Asset]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    asset: (_,{assetName})=> Asset.findOne({assetName : assetName }),
    assetAll: (_,{assetName}) => Asset.find({assetName: assetName})
  }
};

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

React

```
const AssetAllQuery = gql`
{
    assetAll(assetName: $text){
      _id
      assetName
      headline
      firstCreated
      sentimentNegative
      sentimentPositive
      sentimentNeutral
    }
} 
`;



class App extends Component {
  assetAll = async (text) =>{
    await this.props.assetAll({
      variables:{
        assetName: text
      },
      update:(store,{data: {assetAll}}) => {
        const data = store.readQuery({query: AssetAllQuery});
        data.assetAll.unshift(assetAll);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
        const {
            data : { loading, assetAll }
          } = this.props;
        console.log("test");
    if(loading){
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Form submit ={this.getAllAssets}/>
      {assetAll.map(Asset => <div key={Asset._id}>{Asset.headline} | {Asset.sentimentNeutral > Asset.sentimentPositive ?  (Asset.sentimentNeutral > Asset.sentimentNegative ? "Neutral" : "Sell") : "Buy"} </div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default compose(
  graphql(AssetAllQuery, {name: "assetAll"}),
  graphql(AssetQueryInit)
  )(App);
```

Output

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$text" is not defined., Location: [object Object],[object Object], Path: undefined  bundle.js:837:32

[Network error]: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query, any `$variables` you use have to essentially be "declared" as input parameters to the whole thing:

```
const AssetAllQuery = gql`
AssetAll($assetName: String!) {
    assetAll(assetName: $assetName){
        ...
    }
} 
`;
```

The top-level operation name doesn't really matter; the `$variable` has its own declared type and must match what gets used inside the body of the query; and when you make the query, the names of the `variables:` there have to match the names of the declared query parameters.